# unexpected behavior of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular(1.2.1) app with an ng-repeat that looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter:filterList | orderBy:orderList" my-dir>
```

where `filterList` looks something like:

```
$scope.filterList = function(x){
     if (Service.active()){ //tells me whether I need to filter by this field at all
         if (x.field != Service.field()) {
             console.log('FALSE:' + x.id) 
             return false;
         }
     }
      else {...}
    //other clauses like above 
     return true;
}
```

and orderList looks something like:

```
$scope.orderList = function(x){
     return (x.value);
}
```

The unexpected behavior I'm seeing is that, when Service.foo() and/or Service.field( ) change, I expect the contents of my list to change. And indeed they do - the items matching the new value appear at the top of my list, ordered by `value`, as expected. However, **the items that were on the list previously and should have been removed instead remain on the list**, in the same, correct, `value`-sorted order, below the items that should be in the list.

To clarify: If `Service.field() == 'a'` and the list contains objects:

```
field = 'a' value='3'
field = 'a' value='2'
field = 'a' value='1'
```

and then 'Service.field()' changes to `'b'`, I expect to see

```
field = 'b' value='3'
field = 'b' value='2'
field = 'b' value='1'
//nothing else
```

but instead I see:

```
field = 'b' value='3'
field = 'b' value='2'
field = 'b' value='1'
field = 'a' value='3'
field = 'a' value='2'
field = 'a' value='1'
```

would assume it was an issue with changes in the service not being applied to the scope - but a) I've made sure to update the scope; and b) if that was the case, the list would be:

```
field = 'a' value='3'
field = 'b' value='3'
field = 'a' value='2'
field = 'b' value='2'
field = 'a' value='1'
field = 'b' value='1'
```

because `orderList` only doesn't look at field, only value.

**What on Earth could cause this?**

Update: I forgot to mention that the console.log() statement in the filter function **does** print for the items I don't expect to be in the list - so the filter function is returning false, yet the items are not removed.

Update #2: Wow. So, it occurred to me that perhaps an exception was being thrown and swallowed in the filter function and causing this behavior. So, I threw a `i = 3/0` at the top line of it, and sure enough, no exception is thrown to the console. I'm looking into that now. But get this: ***The bug is fixed!*** The repeat, with a filter function that now is obviously broken, works as expected. I suspect this is a strong clue about what my problem is, but I haven't figured out what the clue is pointing to yet.

Comment: 2 elses for the same if? Is that a typo?

Comment: indeed it was, @Brian - thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Are you sure `Service.foo()` returns the same value when `Service.field()` is changed?

Comment: @zsong: Yes, I am. Please see update for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` bind data with `list`, the list object is not changed, so the filter function will not be called.

You should update your list data from some other place, so, check and update the list data repeatedly, like:

```
var checkList = function() {
  $scope.list.forEach(function(data) {
    if (Service.foo()) {data.isShow = true;} // set a mark to display or not
  });
}
$timeout(checkList, 5000); // check every 5 seconds.
```

Then in your ng-repeat, using that mark to determine to display or not.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter: {isShow: true} | orderBy:orderList" my-dir>
```

Comment: This is untrue. The filter function is called when I expect it to be, as confirmed by print statements